# jquery ui selectmenu autofill

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autofill, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I have selectboxes transformed into dropdown menu via jquery ui selectmenu.
My problem is that when I autofill data dropdown menu does not autofills.
only when I press each selectbox when menu drops down, selector selects the right option.

But I need this to be done automatically. How can I achive this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after initialize select menus call

```
$('select').change();
$('select').selectmenu("refresh");
```

---

**Work around** to detect browser autofill is to setTimeout then trigger refresh or change event

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('select').change();
    $('select').selectmenu("refresh");
}, 500);
```

Comment: I've got this error >
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on selectmenu prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Comment: like I said must call it after initalize selectmenu() plugin on select

Comment: you called it before initialization

Comment: does not this $( "select" ).selectmenu() initializes plugin ?

Comment: yes, but to understand more, can you add some code here ?

Comment: I have just this line which converts select boxes into dropdownmenus
$( "select" ).selectmenu();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206956/discussion-between-david-and-abdelrahman-gobarah).

Comment: I've tryied your workaround but I get 
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on selectmenu prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'